# $\text{tr}(AB)=0$ iff $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is antisymmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra

$\text{tr}(AB)=0$ iff $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is antisymmetric.

$\rightarrow$ (Stuck)

$\leftarrow$$\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(AB)^t=\operatorname{tr}(B^tA^t)$

$A$ is symmetric so $A^t=A$, B is antisymmetric $B^t=-B$

$$\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(B^tA^t)=\operatorname{tr}(-BA)=-\operatorname{tr}(BA)=-\operatorname{tr}(AB)$$

$2\operatorname{tr}(AB)=0 \iff \operatorname{tr}(AB)=0$

Can someone help me with the first implication?

Comment: The $\Rightarrow$ implication is not true, for example $A$ is the zero matrix and $B$ is any non-antisymmetric matrix.

Comment: Then, this is only one implication??? If $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is antisymmetric then $tr(AB)=0.$

Comment: @David and this is true? if $A$ is symmetric and $tr(ab)=0$ then B is antisymmetric? i think is false.

Comment: Why do you think it is false?

Comment: $B$ can be the 0 matrix? @David

Comment: The zero matrix is antisymmetric.

Comment: @David and can be and iff and only if?  $A$ is symmetric and $tr(ab)=0$ if and only if $B$ is antisymmetric

Comment: Can you give some reasons?  It sounds like you are just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

$\to$ implication is FALSE.

Take , $\displaystyle A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ & $\displaystyle B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$.

Then , $\displaystyle AB=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$